# How to debug TF-A on ARM Cortex-A7

Tags: arm, stm32, bootloader, cortex-a

I'm trying a custom image for ARM STM32MP151A on a custom board. On power up nothing happens on the tty port (while using a wrong sd-card leads to a PANIC PC error - hence the port is ok). As far as I understand in the early stages of power up sequence, the ROM code should load the FSBL from the dedicated partition. Because the boot type is "trusted" that partition is filled with the TF-A firmware:

```
#Opt    Id      Name        Type        IP      Offset      Binary
-       0x01    fsbl1-boot  Binary      none    0x0         tf-a-stm32mp151a-myproject-mx-trusted.stm32
-       0x03    ssbl-boot   Binary      none    0x0         u-boot-stm32mp151a-myproject-mx-trusted.stm32
P       0x04    fsbl1       Binary      mmc0    0x00004400  tf-a-stm32mp151a-myproject-mx-trusted.stm32
P       0x05    fsbl2       Binary      mmc0    0x00044400  tf-a-stm32mp151a-myproject-mx-trusted.stm32
P       0x06    ssbl        Binary      mmc0    0x00084400  u-boot-stm32mp151a-myproject-mx-trusted.stm32
P       0x21    bootfs      System      mmc0    0x00284400  st-image-bootfs-openstlinux-eglfs-stm32mp1-myproject.ext4
P       0x22    vendorfs    FileSystem  mmc0    0x04284400  st-image-vendorfs-openstlinux-eglfs-stm32mp1-myproject.ext4
P       0x23    rootfs      FileSystem  mmc0    0x05284400  myproject-image-openstlinux-eglfs-stm32mp1-myproject.ext4
P       0x24    userfs      FileSystem  mmc0    0x4E664400  st-image-userfs-openstlinux-eglfs-stm32mp1-myproject.ext4
```

The question is: **how to debug the very first stages of the boot sequence of an ARM-A7** if there's no output on the tty console port?

Comment: Hope you have a board with a JTAG port, and find a hardware JTAG debug probe

Comment: @solidpixel yes, the JTAG port is available. But I never used it with an MPU (only with MCU). I mean, I don't know how to use it to understand what happens during boot.

Comment: How did you debug it in the end? I have the exact same problem right now

Comment: @Legion, I didn't. I wasn't able. Hence I followed a different approach and fortunately it fixed the boot problem.